# Use regex in indexOf and lastIndexOf

Tags: java, regex, indexof, lastindexof

In Java, is there a way to use `indexOf()` or `lastIndexOf()` with a regex expression inside, like used in `replaceAll()`, to find out the indexes (of the first and last indexes of a character) that match the regex expression in the String ?

Comment: Can you provide examples of you are trying to accomplish? Sample input, Expected output? Also, what you've tried and actual output if you have it

Comment: No, these methods don't accept regular expressions. But you can use the regex `Matcher` to repeatedly `find()` matches, then get detailed index values using the `start`, `end` and `group` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Forexample here is a regex pattern which finds 3 'w' next to each other.
`m.find()` tries to find a match and returns true if it succeeds.
By using `m.start()` after each `m.find()` you get the first index of the found match and by `m.end()` you get last index of found match

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("w{3}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("www lskjdflkj www sdflkjslkjlk fsdlkfjww lksjfkjwww sldklk wwwlskjdflkjwwwlkjlj lkj");
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println("start index:"+m.start()+", end index:"+m.end());
    }
```

output:

```
start index:0, end index:3
start index:14, end index:17
start index:48, end index:51
start index:59, end index:62
start index:71, end index:74
```

You can store the found indexes in a HashMap or something else to use later(if you need to)